# Trigger Azure alert from function app script with context

Tags: azure, powershell

Is there any way to trigger Azure Alert results by PowerShell script in the function app and attach results? I would like to pass the result of $res to the Azure Alert and send the email.

```
$res = Get-AzResourceGroup

$actionEmail = New-AzActionGroupReceiver `
  -Name "Admin" `
  -EmailAddress "test@test.com" 

$actionGroup = Set-AzActionGroup `
  -Name "notify-admins" `
  -ShortName "ActionGroup1" `
  -ResourceGroupName "test-group" `
  -Receiver $actionEmail
```

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878968/update-action-group-with-multiple-email-receivers-set-azactiongroup?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, you can trigger an Azure Alert from a function app script using PowerShell. You can use the `New-AzActionGroupReceiver` cmdlet to create an email action group and the `Set-AzActionGroup` cmdlet to set the action group. You can pass the result of `$res` to the Azure Alert and send the email.

I have used the below code in the Function App to trigger an email.

1. Create a function App.
2. And create a rule and create an alert and create an action group   and bind them together using Azure portal.

```
Get-AzAlertRule -ResourceGroup "YourResourceGrp" -Name "newalertruke" -DetailedOutput  
$actionEmail = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name "Admin" -EmailAddress "test@testmail.com" -FunctionAppResourceId "/subscriptions/`SubscrptionId`/resourceGroups/"YourResourceGrp"/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/newjahnavifunc" -FunctionName "HttpTrigger1"  
$actionGroup = Set-AzActionGroup `  
-Name "notify-admins" `  
-ShortName "myaction" `  
-ResourceGroupName "YourResourceGrp" `  
-Receiver $actionEmail
```

Received email alerts.

[image]

Reference taken from [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/new-azactiongroupreceiver?view=azps-9.4.0) and [MSDoc2.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/powershell.md)